# Не работает проверка существования таблицы sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

ДВС! У меня задача, проверить базу SQLite на существование таблицы. Везде рекомендуется способ:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mysqlite.db')
c = conn.cursor()
            
#get the count of tables with the name
c.execute(''' SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='students1' ''')

#if the count is 1, then table exists
if c.fetchone()[0]==1 : 
    print('Table exists.')
else :
    print('Table does not exist.')
```

Но у меня он почему то не работает, а просто возникает исключение и код останавливается

```
Возникло исключение: OperationalError
no such column:students1
```

Средство самого sql: if not exists, мне не подойдет, так как и сам код питона будет отличаться при наличии таблицы.
Подскажите, как это исправить?
Спасибо!

Comment: Ваш код работает на моем компьютере windows 10. Нужны дополнительные данные -  ваша система, работаете ли с БД через фреймворк и т.д.

Comment: Можно попробовать современное `sqlite_schema` вместо `sqlite_master`
 https://www.sqlite.org/schematab.html

Comment: После оборота всего этого в try, заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исключение `OperationalError` возникает из-за того, что не получилось произвести запрос из базы данных по одной из двух причин:

1. Из-за отсутствия таблицы - исключение
   `OperationalError: no such table`
2. Из-за отсутствия столбца в таблице - исключение `OperationalError: no such column`

В вашем коде (строка `c.execute(...)`) - это исключение не обрабатывается, поэтому приложение завершает свою работу с ошибкой.

Для корректного продолжения требуется отловить исключение при помощи конструкции `try/except`:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mysqlite.db')
c = conn.cursor()
            
try:
  c.execute(''' SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='students1' ''')
  data_list = c.fetchall() 
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
  print('Something goes wrong')
```

> Задача: проверить базу SQLite на существование таблицы

Но этот код проверяет не только существование таблицы, но и существование столбца `students1`, что не соответствует условию задачи, поскольку при существовании таблицы, но отсутствии столбца `students1`, все равно будет вызвано исключение.

Для проверки существования только таблицы достаточно в вашем запросе убрать дополнительную фильтрацию по столбцу и тогда исключение `OperationalError` не будет возникать по другим причинам.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mysqlite.db')
c = conn.cursor()
            
try:
  table_name = 'table'
  c.execute(''' SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=table_name''')
  data_list = c.fetchall() 
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
  print(f'Table {table_name} doesnt exist')
```